Is "estop" a good alternative for academic writing instead of "preclude"?
I want to convey a message in the abstract of a scientific paper that I am writing that says:
"Due to A (some principle), it estops (precludes) the use of classical ....". Is it too fancy? The word "preclude" is used a lot that is why I wanted something different that attracts the reader.

Abstracts are supposed to be quickly readable and understandable; in many fields by people for whom English is not a first language. They're not the opportunity to use your weird Scrabble words. At least if you want people to read and cite your paper.

M-W, for instance, says that apart from the legal specifying definition, this word is obsolete.

I don't think I speak for everybody but I ain't never heard of no 'ee-stop'. Is that some kind of way to stop email? Then I'm all for it!

@Mitch haha! Definitely, it should be a word. :D

This question should not have been closed. It is a question about style and usage, not a dictionary question.

Keep in mind that scientific papers are often read by people whose first language is not English. It may be to your benefit to give more weight to clarity than style.

@jimm101 Yes, I understand. It is always a bit difficult to make a very nice beginning to keep the attention of the readers and not sound fancy at the same time :D

@Vector It is reopened now :D

I do not really understand the downvote, even though everyone in the comments and answers liked the discussion.

No. Estop is not a good alternative for preclude.
Estop has a specific meaning and is used only where it means to preclude by estoppel.

estoppel law
a rule of evidence whereby a person is precluded from denying the truth of a statement of facts he or she has previously asserted.
Collins

You may be able to use prevent or even simply stop, although some rewording might be needed.

Thanks for the reply. I did not know about estoppel.
